# Link a local git repository with an existing repository

Tags: git

I'm working on a C project with some friends for school. They helped me to set up everything on my debian partition but I would like to do the same things with Windows. I created an empty local repository but now I would like to "link" it with our project so that I can commit on my branch.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not create an empty local repository. Just clone the origin
again on your windows partition (`git clone url://to/origin`).

If you don't know the url for origin, you can try the following steps
(after adapting for your local setup).

On your Debian partition:

```
cd <working directory>
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

The url given by the second command is your url for origin. Then on your
Windows partition you can do `git clone <url you got above>`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even after all this time... I completely forgot that I asked it. I also completely forgot that I just had to clone the repository instead of trying to create a local repository... Shame on me.